# How to allow HTTP requests to other docker containers with RSpec?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, docker, rspec, webmock

I have a docker project with a few different moving parts, and I want one container to be able to call the API of another container.

However, sending any kind of request in my rspec tests yields:

> WebMock::NetConnectNotAllowedError: Real HTTP connections are
>   disabled. Unregistered request: ...

How can I allow it to call the other container?

Comment: In your Dockerfile you must put `EXPOSE xx` where xx is the port you want to expose to other containers

Comment: In addition to Docker config you would have to tell rspec to allow the HTTP requests. See the "Real requests to network can be allowed or disabled" section on the [webmock readme](https://github.com/bblimke/webmock). By the way, the reason HTTP requests are often disabled/mocked in tests is that it makes the tests run faster.